# How to display a UIView which overlaps the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar, mainscreen

In my application, I want to initiate a `UIView` that overlaps and dims the whole screen including the `UINavigationBar`, the code is as below:

```
- (void)showInstruction
{
    self.holedView = [[JMHoledView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.holedView];
}
```

but indeed the `self.holedView` can only dims the district without the `UINavigationBar` on the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you are trying to achive?

Comment: Add your view to `self.view.window`

Comment: Sorry I must have 10 reputations to post a image T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add view as a subview to the window's or navigation controller's view.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourView];
```

OR

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:yourView];
```

Create view's delegate to remove it from superview whenever needed

Comment: Or as the comment said, add myview to self.view.window; there are some differences and I'm trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

You can use dimmed transparent image and set it as background image of navigation bar.

For eg In my case , I made black transparent image of alpha 0.2 and set it as navigation background image and made the background color clear color

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_patch.png"]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;
navController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to add subView in the main window:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to the window

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *backgrView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
backgrView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
backgrView.alpha = 0.6;
[[appDelegate window] addSubview:backgrView];
```

or

```
Try navigationBar.translucent = NO; , It is YES by default in iOS7.


 So you can add a version check like this:

 float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion >= 7.0)
{
 navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```